# RxJava: how to fallback for not supported Observables when using onType()?

Tags: rx-java2

Say I have

```
// Function<? super Observable<T>, ? extends ObservableSource<R>> selector
source -> Observable.merge(
    source.ofType(A.class).compose(transformerA),
    source.ofType(B.class).compose(transformerB)
);
```

Is there a clever way to throw an error if `source` happens to be neither of type `A` nor `B` so I could detect missing implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a filter pass through if the source value is of neither type and flatMap the unknown element into an error:

```
source -> Observable.merge(
    source.ofType(A.class).compose(transformerA),
    source.ofType(B.class).compose(transformerB),
    source.filter(v -> !(v instanceof A) && !(v instanceof B))
        .flatMap(w -> 
            Observable.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + w)) 
);
```

And yes, if there is a type `C` that gets a handler, you have to extend the pattern.